# Reserving a range of IDs in wxPython

Tags: python, xml, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm writing a somewhat larger GUI application in wxPython for I2C devices. When the program starts, it dynamically generates a menu of devices from an XML file. It starts by appending a submenu for each 'type' of device (EEPROM, Multiplexer, IOExpander, etc) and then in each submenu, appends the names of the actual devices. Because the menu isn't created until run-time, I have to assign IDs on the fly. Also, because the XML file will be updated from time to time with new "types" of devices, I need to know not only which item was selected, but which from which submenu the item came from. The current way I am implementing this is by having a "parent-child" relationship in the ID I'm assigning the item. Currently, the ID of one of these menu items is a 3 digit number: the first digit will always be 2, so I know it came from the devices menu. The second digit is the submenu the selection came from, and the final digit is the specific device selected. In order to store these IDs, I add them to a dictionary, where the ID is the key and the name of the device is the value.

```
submenu_id = -1
    for device_type in self.device_list:
        submenu = wx.Menu()
        submenu_id += 1
        device_menu_id = -1
        for device in device_type.m_device_list:
            device_menu_id += 1
            device_id = 200 + (submenu_id * 10) + device_menu_id
            id_list[device_id] = device.m_name
            item = wx.MenuItem(submenu, device_id, device.m_name, wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
            submenu.AppendItem(item)
        menu.AppendSubMenu(submenu, device_type.m_name)
```

Now, I have two problems with this. The most immediate problem is that I need to reserve the range of IDs from 200 to 299, which encompass all possible IDs that could be assigned to a device item. If I call wx.ID_ANY, it will sometimes assign IDs in that range for other menus, which means my bindings are all screwed up. The other problem is that I feel this is a bit of a contrived way to do this. Currently, I can only have 10 different types of device submenus each with only 10 devices in them. For the foreseeable future, this should be enough, however I'd like to be able to add as many devices in as many different categories as possible. Also, the code to do this is pretty ugly and obfuscated, and I'd really like for somebody reading my code to know what the heck I'm doing.

So, my first question is: Is there a way to reserve the range of IDs that I need so I won't get any conflicts with wx?

And my second question, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `wx.RegisterId(id)`.  In a nutshell, `wx.NewId` is pretty simple-minded.  It just increments an internal counter and returns the value with no additional smarts.  If you use `wx.RegisterId(id)` then that counter is set to the value given so the next one returned by `wx.NewId` will be > id.  So you can set it to some value and then everything below that value (which is not already reserved for system IDs, like wx.ID_OK) can be used as explicit IDs by your code.  Be aware however that the automatic IDs can possiblly wrap around if you are using thousands of `wx.ID_ANY` or `wx.NewID()` IDs throughout the life of the application run.

As to a better approach, I think I would just use `wx.ID_ANY` and then use a dictionary to map the menu id assigned to the item to the real data obect.  This way the IDs (which are really just an implementation detail associated with the UI, not the data model) have no real meaning in and of themselves, but they can be used in menu event handlers to easily get to the real data that is pertinent to the application. For example:

```
    item = menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Foo")
    self.menuIdMap[item.GetId()] = someDataObjectForFoo
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnMenuItemSelected, item)
```

And then:

```
def OnMenuItemSelected(self, evt):
    dataObj = self.menuIdMap[evt.GetId()]
    dataObj.doSomething()
```

Comment: This was the way I was doing it, but I need to know both what the item is and which submenu it came from. That's why I need to make the IDs myself (or until I find a better alternative).

Comment: What about adding the submenu to the menuIdMap?  You could use item.GetMenu() to get the submenu.

Comment: Or add something that represents the position in the menu hierarchy to the data object referred to by the menuIdMap.  Perhaps a reference to the parent data object, or similar.